# Confluence Plugin

Tags: java, netbeans, sdk, confluence

I am going to develop Confluence plugin using JAVA .I downloaded Confluence SDK and installed in my local machine. We don not know how to create plugin project in either Netbeans or Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atlassian has e very good documentation about this:

- [Create a HelloWorld Plugin Project](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Create+a+HelloWorld+Plugin+Project)
- [Set Up the Eclipse IDE for Windows](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Set+Up+the+Eclipse+IDE+for+Windows)
- [Set up the Atlassian Plugin SDK and Build a Project](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Set+up+the+Atlassian+Plugin+SDK+and+Build+a+Project)

Also have a look at:

- [Confluence Plugin Guide](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Confluence+Plugin+Guide)
- [Writing Confluence Plugins](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Writing+Confluence+Plugins)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried that?

https://wiki.base22.com/display/btg/Setting+Up+Your+Environment+for+Confluence+Plugin+Development#SettingUpYourEnvironmentforConfluencePluginDevelopment-Importprojectintoeclipse

A simple Google search should be enough...

Comment: This page is from Jan 06, 2010 and oudated. As it says on the page itself it only applies for plugin development for Confluence up to version 2.9.